# A generic problem found in the process of using swagger2

Tags: java, swagger

While working with swagger2, I found this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGXtT.png)

why can swagger2 display generics, don't generics erase during compilation?
This is one of my attempts!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo75j.png)

I hope we can solve this problem!